# Align windows on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop-environments

If I drag a window to the left or right edge of the screen in Windows, Windows will tack it to that edge and resize it to occupy half the screen.

On some Linux desktops, this also works in dual display setups: if I have two screens next to each other, I can arrange up to four windows next to each other in this manner.

On Windows 7, this behavior seems to work only on the outer edges. I can make one window take up the left half of the left screen, but not the right half of the left screen. Is this behavior configurable, and if so, where?

Answer (score 0):

If both screens are the same size, the following workaround may work:

- Drag the window to the right edge of the right screen.
- Press `Win` + `Shift` + `←`

Now the window is occupying the right half of the left screen.

Still just a workaround though, not a perfect solution.